# Returning an updated list on increase in number of files

Tags: python, flask

I want to return the updated list with the new file name in the list without explicitly refreshing the server..
This is my backend code written in flask :-

```
@app.route("/list")
def return_list():
    all_files = os.listdir(r'H:/JS/uploads/')
    files_without_extension = []

for file in all_files:
    temp = os.path.splitext(file)
    if(temp[1] == ".json" ):
        files_without_extension.append(temp[0].title())


print("Total number of files : {}".format(len(all_files)))
print(files_without_extension)

return jsonify(files_without_extension)
```

The problem is when I refresh my web page, the list is being updated. I want the list to be updated if there are files removed or added in the directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can only achieve this with [websockets](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

An alternative solution is to update the page regularly. The user who deletes a file himself is redirected.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">

@app.route('/list')
def uploads_list():
    def _froot(fname):
        root,_ = os.path.splitext(fname)
        return root
    return jsonify(_froot(fname) for fname in glob.iglob('H:/JS/uploads/*.json'))

@app.route('/remove/<path:fname>', methods=['POST'])
def uploads_remove(fname):
    if os.path.exists(f'{fname}.json'):
        try:
            os.remove(f'{fname}.json')
        except OSError as err: pass
    return redirect(url_for('uploads_list'))
```

Comment: I have not worked with web sockets before..thanks for your suggestion...As far as refreshing goes.. I am using react so it refreshes which definitely works but not the optimized solution I am after.